# Django - 'WhereNode' object has no attribute 'output_field' error

Tags: django, django-models, django-2.0, django-aggregation, django-annotate

I am trying to query and annotate some data from my models:

```
class Feed(models.Model):     # Feed of content
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Piece(models.Model):    # Piece of content (video or playlist)
    removed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    feed    = models.ForeignKey(Feed, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user    = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Other fields are not used in the following queries so I skipped them here.

In my view I need to get queryset of all feeds of an authenticated user. Annotation should contain quantity of all pieces that are not removed.

Initially, `Piece` model didn't contain `removed` field and everything worked great with the queryset like this:

```
Feed.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).annotate(Count('piece'))
```

But then I added the field `removed` to `Piece` model and needed to count only pieces that were not *removed*:

```
Feed.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
            .annotate(Count('piece'), filter=Q(piece__removed=False))
```

It gave me the following error:

```
'WhereNode' object has no attribute 'output_field'
```

It is only a little fraction of what django outputs on the error page, so if it is not enough, please let me know what else I need to include in my question.

I tried to include `output_field` with options like `models.IntegerField()` or `models.FloatField()` (properly imported) here and there but got some errors which I do not provide here because I believe those actions made no sense.

I am using Django 2.0.3

Comment: Your syntax mistake is here, `Feed.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
            .annotate(Count('piece', filter=Q(piece__removed=False)))`

Comment: Thank you so much! I looked everywhere, but didn't check those parentheses. I believe your comment should be an answer.

Comment: I'm adding this as an answer, so you can accept.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your syntax mistake is here,

```
Feed.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
            .annotate(Count('piece', filter=Q(piece__removed=False)))
```

filter needs to apply at `Count` not at `annotate`.

Reference from Django's documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations